# Pass and get a DOM element value in Angular JS Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

I am really new in Angular JS

I have one html page,which loads a js file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-iframe/dist/adf-widget-iframe.min.js"></script>
```

that file (adf-widget-iframe.min.js) content is given below

```
! function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("adf.widget.iframe", ["adf.provider"]).config(["dashboardProvider", function(e) {
        e.widget("iframe", {
            title: "iframe",
            description: "Embed an external page into the dashboard",
            templateUrl: "{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/view.html",
            controller: "iframeController",
            controllerAs: "iframe",
            edit: {
                templateUrl: "{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/edit.html"
            },
            config: {
                height: "420px"
            }
        })
    }]).controller("iframeController", ["$sce", "config", function(e, r) {
        r.url && (this.url = e.trustAsResourceUrl(r.url))
    }]), angular.module("adf.widget.iframe").run(["$templateCache", function(e) {
        e.put("{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/edit.html", "<form role=form><div class=form-group><label for=url>URL</label> 

<input type=url class=form-control id=url ng-model=config.url placeholder=http://www.example.com>
//Here i need to put url from html page like from a text box.

</div><div class=form-group><label for=url>Height</label> <input type=text class=form-control id=url ng-model=config.height></div></form>"), e.put("{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/view.html", '<div><div class="alert alert-info" ng-if=!config.url>Please insert a url in the widget configuration</div><iframe ng-if=iframe.url class=adf-iframe style="height: {{config.height}}" src={{iframe.url}}></iframe></div>')
    }])
}(window);
```

In the above code i have to get a value from the html page and need to put in the place of url as shown in the cone( i have commented out there.)

can anybody help me to how to put the text box data in the place of URL?

Its My html file

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="dashboard sample app">
    <meta name="author" content="Sebastian Sdorra">

    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <!-- build:css css/sample.min.css -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- dashboard style -->
    <link href="components/angular-dashboard-framework/dist/angular-dashboard-framework.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="components/adf-widget-clock/dist/adf-widget-clock.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="components/adf-widget-iframe/dist/adf-widget-iframe.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('adf-dashboard');
        document.createElement('adf-widget');
        document.createElement('adf-widget-content');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>

  <body ng-app="adfDynamicSample">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container" ng-controller="navigationCtrl as nav">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="nav.toggleNav()">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ADF Dynamic Sample</a>
        </div>
        <div collapse="nav.navCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ng-class="nav.navClass('boards/' + item.id)" ng-repeat="item in nav.items | orderBy: title">
              <a ng-href="#/boards/{{item.id}}">{{item.title}}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a style="cursor: pointer;" ng-click="nav.create()">Create</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <ng-view />

    </div>

    <!-- components -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/Sortable/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-dashboard-framework/dist/angular-dashboard-framework.min.js"></script>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>

    <!-- structures -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-structures-base/dist/adf-structures-base.min.js"></script>

    <!-- clock -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-clock/dist/adf-widget-clock.min.js"></script>

    <!-- github -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/highcharts/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-github/dist/adf-widget-github.min.js"></script>

    <!-- iframe -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-iframe/dist/adf-widget-iframe.min.js"></script>

    <!-- linklist -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-linklist/dist/adf-widget-linklist.min.js"></script>

    <!-- markdown -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/showdown/compressed/Showdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-markdown-directive/markdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-markdown/dist/adf-widget-markdown.min.js"></script>

    <!-- news -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-news/dist/adf-widget-news.min.js"></script>

    <!-- randommsg -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-randommsg/dist/adf-widget-randommsg.min.js"></script>

    <!-- version -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-version/dist/adf-widget-version.min.js"></script>

    <!-- weather -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-weather/dist/adf-widget-weather.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Its my referring dashboard GUI,
i am working with this dashboard Example

```
https://github.com/angular-dashboard-framework/adf-dynamic-example
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question correctly, we are trying to pass URL of current page when adding new `iframe`.

If above is true, here is my solution:

- Inject `$location` into controller
- Get absolute path of current page: `$location.$$absUrl`
- Use absolute path value in `$templateCache`

You can both use URL string as placeholder for input, or as input value. If it used as input value, `iframe` gets created instantly, since by original design it should be null

In GUI it's going to look something like this: 
[image: iframe dialogbox]

Content of **adf-widget-iframe.js**:

```
(function(window, undefined) {'use strict';


angular.module('adf.widget.iframe', ['adf.provider'])
    .config(["dashboardProvider", function(dashboardProvider){
        dashboardProvider
            .widget('iframe', {
                title: 'iframe',
                description: 'Embed an external page into the dashboard',
                templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/view.html',
                controller: 'iframeController',
                controllerAs: 'iframe',
                edit: {
                    templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/edit.html'
                },
                config: {
                    height: '420px'
                }
            });
    }])
    .controller('iframeController', ["$sce", "config", "$location", function($sce, config, $location){
        config.placeholder = $location.$$absUrl;
        if (config.url){
            this.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(config.url);
        }
    }]);

angular.module("adf.widget.iframe").run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put("{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/edit.html","<form role=form><div class=form-group><label for=url>URL</label> <input type=url class=form-control id=url ng-model=config.url placeholder={{config.placeholder}}></div><div class=form-group><label for=url>Height</label> <input type=text class=form-control id=url ng-model=config.height></div></form>");
$templateCache.put("{widgetsPath}/iframe/src/view.html","<div><div class=\"alert alert-info\" ng-if=!config.url>Please insert a url in the widget configuration</div><iframe ng-if=iframe.url class=adf-iframe style=\"height: {{config.height}}\" src={{iframe.url}}></iframe></div>");}]);})(window);
```

Don't forget to actually import not minified file into **index.html**:

```
<!-- iframe -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/adf-widget-iframe/dist/adf-widget-iframe.js"></script>
```